# How can I use a Tiny MCE editor in my custom Gutenberg block?

Tags: customization, block-editor

I am building a custom block where I would like to use the Tiny MCE editor for content entry rather than the RichText component that ships with Gutenberg.

I am making this choice because I can't see a way to support entering both a regular paragraph and an unordered list into a single RichText field. I need a rich text editor that is more robust, able to support entry of paragraphs, lists and even nested lists. I find Tiny MCE well suited for my requirements.

How can I integrate the Tiny MCE editor into my custom block? Or is there a way to set up the RichText component to support both lists and paragraphs? I am using Wordpress v5.1.1.